# use LINQ to XML to Programmatically get all differences between 2 xml files

Tags: c#, xml, linq, except

I am using c sharp 5.0 and using LINQ to XML I try to programmatically get the differences between 2 xml files 
my first files is as simple as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<table name="MYTABLE">
<columns>
<column name="MY_ID" type="NUMBER"/> 
<column name="M_NAME" type="VARCHAR2" /> 
<column name="MY_PARENT_ID" type="VARCHAR2" /> 
<column name="MY_CAPTION" type="VARCHAR2" />
</columns>
</table>
```

and my second xml file is as simple as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<table name=" MYTABLE ">
<columns>
<column name="MY_ID" type="NUMBER"/> 
<column name="M_NAME" type="VARCHAR2" /> 
<column name="MY_PARENT_ID" type="NUMBER" />
</columns>
</table>
```

and my code is as simple as :

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"Path\table1.xml");
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(@"Path\table2.xml");
var cols1 = doc1.Descendants("column") ;
var cols2 = doc2.Descendants("column") ;
var itemsOnFirstFileOnly = cols1.Except(cols2);
var itemsOnSecondFileOnly = cols2.Except(cols1);
```

but to my surprise  itemsOnFirstFileOnly returned ALL of columns that exist on table1.xml (not only MY_PARENT_ID & MY_CAPTION ) and itemsOnSecondFileOnly returned ALL of the columns that exist in table2.xml (not only MY_PARENT_ID),so why not Except doesn’t work as expected ??

Comment: try providing [XNodeEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348073.aspx), which uses [DeepEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx), to the `Except` method. Without it, probably only the references of the two elements are compared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement `Equals` on your `Column`-class so that `Except` knows when two `Columns` are equal:

```
class Column 
{
    bool Equals(object other) 
    {
        // ...
        // skip further checks for simplicity
        // ...

        Column o = (Column) other;
        return o.Name == this.Name && o.Type == this.Type  ;
    }
}
```

If you do not implement this method `Except` will just check for reference-equality which can never be true because your columns come from differenct contexts (files in your case).

EDIT: As you are comparing `XNodes` the thing is much easier because you can use the `XNodeEqualityComparer`-class which has its own `Equals`-implementation that exactly fit your needs as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348073.aspx). Thus the following should work:

```
var itemsOnFirstFileOnly = cols1.Except(cols2, new XNodeEqualityComparer());
```

Comment: Looks like OP is comparing XNodes. Can't easily provide an implementation of Equals there.

Comment: @Corak Yeap, you´re right, hopefully the update is correct now.

Comment: yes, it worked correctly just after I added "new XNodeEqualityComparer" parameter to the Except method without the need to implement Equals,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Linq:

```
var itemsOnFirstFileOnly = cols1.Where(x => !cols2.Select(y => y.Attribute("name").Value).Contains(x.Attribute("name").Value));
var itemsOnSecondFileOnly = cols2.Where(x => !cols1.Select(y => y.Attribute("name").Value).Contains(x.Attribute("name").Value));
```

Basically in the above code:

- Selects the value of the `name` attributes
- Compares these names
- Returns the `XElement` instances where the name is missing in the other collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the `XElement`s to strings, which takes attributes into account:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Parse(xml2);

var diffs = doc.Descendants().Select(e => e.ToString())
            .Except(doc2.Descendants().Select(e => e.ToString()));

foreach (var e in diffs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Considering columns, this returns only

```
<column name="MY_PARENT_ID" type="VARCHAR2" />

<column name="MY_CAPTION" type="VARCHAR2" />
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise against using the `string` representation for equality checks here (and most other places), as it has horrible performance. In this case, your `docA.Descendants().Select(e => e.ToString()).Except(docB.Descendants().Select(e => e.ToString()))` is about 16 times slower than `docA.Descendants().Except(docB.Descendants(), new XNodeEqualityComparer())`.